# Gradle 7.3.1. giving error when building with module-info.java having 3rd party jars

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, java-module

I have a java module with many 3rd party jars added. I am migrating the java 8 project to java 17. I have added the module-info.java file with all the 3rd party dependencies.

```
module com.ib.core {
exports com.ib.core.interfaces.dbserver.projects;
exports com.ib.core.rmi;
exports com.ib.core.interfaces.castor.common;
exports com.ib.core.bo.struct.datasource.connector.riversand.bo.config;
exports com.ib.core.interfaces.dbserver.projects.versioning;
exports com.ib.core.utils;
exports com.ib.core.bo.holders;
requires java.xml;
requires commons.io;
requires dom4j;
requires software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3;
requires com.arangodb.core;
requires com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;
requires org.apache.logging.log4j;
requires jackson.mapper.asl;
requires java.rmi;
requires java.sql;
requires java.ws.rs;}
```

I have the libraries added in Core/lib/all the jars
below is my classpath sample

```
      <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main"/>
      <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/generated"/>
       <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/obfuscated"/>
      <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/commons-io-2.5.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="module" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jaxb-api-2.4.0-b180830.0359.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="module" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/dom4j-2.0.3.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="module" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
```

and below is my gradle script

```css
buildscript {
      repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        flatDir {
            dir("C:/BuildUtils/proguard")
        }
      }
      dependencies {
            classpath ("com.guardsquare:proguard-gradle:7.3.2")
        }
    }

    plugins {
        java
        id ("com.zyxist.chainsaw") version "0.3.1" apply false
    }

    sourceSets {
       getByName("main").java.srcDirs("src/main", "src/generation", "src/obfuscated") 
    }

    // In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
    repositories {
       flatDir {
           dir("lib")
       }
    }

    val licenseManager = configurations.create("licenseManager")


    dependencies {
        licenseManager(project(path = ":LicenseManager", configuration = "applib"))
        implementation(project(path = ":LicenseManager", configuration = "applib"))
        implementation(fileTree("lib") { 
           include("*.jar")
        })
        
        implementation(fileTree("$rootDir/IBCore/lib/awsarango") { 
           include("*.jar")
        })
        "licenseManager"(fileTree("$rootDir/IBCore/lib") { 
           include("*.jar")
        })

    }

    ant.withGroovyBuilder {
        "taskdef"("resource" to "tasks.properties") {
            "classpath" {
                "fileset"("dir" to "C:/BuildUtils/encrypt", "includes" to "encrypt.jar")    
            }
        }
    }

    val coreClasses = listOf("com/ib/core/secure/**/*", "com/ib/core/obfuscated/**/*", "com/ib/licensemanager/secure/**/*", "com/ib/licensemanager/obfuscated/**/*")
    val coreResources = listOf("**/serverstore", "**/creator_private")
    val encryptedCoreResources = file("$buildDir/tmp_encrypt/core")
    val jarMetaFiles = listOf("META-INF/*.DSA", "META-INF/*.RSA", "META-INF/*.SF")

    val ibCoreJarForRelease = tasks.create<Jar>("ibCoreJarForRelease") {
        dependsOn("compileJava")
        group = "Build"
        archiveName = "IBCore.jar"
        description = "Builds fat runnable jarForRelease for " + project.name
        destinationDir = file("$buildDir/dist")
        from(licenseManager.filter { it.name.endsWith("LicenseManager.jar") }.map { zipTree(it) })
        from(sourceSets["main"].output)
        from(sourceSets["main"].java.srcDirs) {
          exclude("**/*.java")
        }
        exclude(coreClasses)
        exclude(coreResources)
        exclude(jarMetaFiles)
        includeEmptyDirs = false
        manifest {
            attributes("Built-By" ABC, "Class-Path" to "../Libraries/Core/core.jar")
        }
    }
```

when I run this, I get the following error

```css
Task :IBCore:compileJava FAILED
    D:\InBetween\IBCore\src\main\module-info.java:64: error: module not found: commons.io
            requires commons.io;
                            ^
    D:\InBetween\IBCore\src\main\module-info.java:69: error: module not found: jackson.mapper.asl
            requires jackson.mapper.asl;
                                   ^
    D:\InBetween\IBCore\src\main\module-info.java:73: error: module not found: org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client
            requires org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client;
                                           ^
    D:\InBetween\IBCore\src\main\module-info.java:75: error: module not found: jackson.core.asl
            requires jackson.core.asl;
                                 ^
    D:\InBetween\IBCore\src\main\module-info.java:76: error: module not found: dom4j
            requires dom4j;
                     ^
    5 errors
```

As you can see in the dependencies, I have added the file tree and included all the jars from lib. it compiles totally fine in eclipse.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how I can fix it?